# Passing variable from service to activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm trying to pass variable in my service class VandroidService2 to my activity class VandroidServiceClient:
Here is the code to send the varible that is in VandroidService2:

```
         long accel = 8987; 
         Intent myIntent = new Intent(VandroidService2.this,VandroidServiceClient.class);
         myIntent.putExtra("accel1", accel);
```

Here is the code I used to receive it in VandroidServiceClient:

```
           TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
           Intent mIntent = getIntent();
           long lovalue = mIntent.getLongExtra("accel1", 0);
           textView.setText(String.valueOf(lovalue));
```

For some reason the default variable 0 is being displayed to the screen? What am I do wrong and is more information needed to help me?

Comment: It looks like it should work... I assume you use `startActivity(myIntent);` in VandroidService2?

Comment: I used this.startActivity(myIntent)

Answer (score 2):

Try `intent.getExtras()`, check if not null, if not null then `.getLong("accel1", 0);`

If you are ***sure*** at what you have done previously, this will work.

Comment: Are talking about some like:                                   mIntent.getExtras(); if(mIntent.getExtras() != null)
{
 long lovalue = mIntent.getLong("accel1", 0);
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(lovalue));//}
}

Comment: `mIntent.getExtras().getLong("name", defaultvalue);`